# How to use a method in a controller to verify a form input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Here's the function I want:**

1. Form gets submitted
2. Form inputs `valid?`
3. Form input (specific input) verifies through API via `verify` method
4. if true, begins next function

**Here's the code i currently have for create:**

```
def create
    @tweet_order = TweetOrder.new(tweet_order_params)
    @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])

    @tweet_order.order_id = @order.id

      if @tweet_order.valid?
        begin
          #Stripe_charge_

            rescue Stripe::CardError => e
              charge_error = e.message
            end
            if charge_error
              flash[:error] = charge_error
              redirect_to @order
            else

              if @tweet_order.save
              ....
```

**Here's along the lines I want:**

```
def verify
    TwitterApi.client.search("to:#{@order.twitter_tag}", result_type: "recent").take(10).collect do |tweet|
       tweet.user.screen_name if tweet.user.screen_name.match(/#{@order.listing.listing_tweet.twitter_id}/i)
    end
end

def create
    @tweet_order = TweetOrder.new(tweet_order_params)
    @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])

    @tweet_order.order_id = @order.id

      if @tweet_order.valid? && verify
        begin
          #Stripe_charge_

            rescue Stripe::CardError => e
              charge_error = e.message
            end
            if charge_error
              flash[:error] = charge_error
              redirect_to @order
            else

              if @tweet_order.save
              ....
```

**Note the difference:**
`@tweet_order.valid?`  vs  `@tweet_order.valid? && verify`

What the verify method does is creates a `true` or `false`.  I have tested this in the front end view and it works but now I want to implement it for verifying before creating the stripe charge and saving the create.

How can I go about successfully and efficiently doing this?

Comment: Your `verify` method is not returnin true/false, it's returning an array, maybe you want to call `any?` or `empty?` on it.

Comment: Couldn't i "return true if.... " or what do you think a piece of code should be? And as for the create method, would the `&& verify` work the way i think it will once i fix the verify method itself?

Comment: I also updated the verify method.  removed the @user_result as they shouldn't be needed for just the true/false when calling it

Comment: I also believe adding a `?` to `.match`will create a true/false.  ?

Comment: For anyone coming along.  I am mostly wondering about calling the `verify` method within the `create` controller.  I need a way, where if `true`, the stripe code begins

Comment: I'm not sure what you want the `verify` method to do. You want to check if at least one of the elements of the loop matches the tweet's user name? one? all? none? As for adding the "?" to `.match`, why do you believe that? don't guess, use the language docs. I'm not sure what's the way you think it should work, but instead of asking, first fix the method and then just try it.

Comment: Because that's what .match? is supposed to do.  Return a true or false. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#method-i-match-3F